# How to get value from nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have written a function which will return several dictionaries.
For example:

```
def func()
    return c # <---- nested dictionary

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ans = func()
    print ans
```

If I print the ans:

```
{u'ok': 1.0, u'result': [{u'price': 129.7, u'_id': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 23, 9, 32)}, {u'price': 129.78, u'_id': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 23, 9, 33)},
print ans.get('_id')
```

If I print this, the result is None.
How can I get `_id`?

Comment: ans.get('result')[0].get('_id') ?

Comment: I can get the result , but only the first one..
how can get all results?

Comment: `[i['_id'] for i in ans['result']]`

Comment: the 0 is the first index. for the remaining, you could use a for loop

Comment: I can get all results!!
thank all of you!!!!

Comment: @manChan accept an answer which helps you the most.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, new user can't accept until they have 15 rep.

Comment: @manChan: this is actually called a **nested dictionary**. Look closely at what your print is telling you.

Comment: @smci he can able to accept but he can't put an up or downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension.

```
In [19]: ans = {u'ok': 1.0, u'result': [{u'price': 129.7, u'_id': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 23, 9, 32)}, {u'price': 129.78, u'_id': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 23, 9, 33)}]}
In [24]: [i['_id'] for i in ans['result']]
Out[24]: [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 23, 9, 32), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 23, 9, 33)]
In [25]: [i.get('_id') for i in ans['result']]
Out[25]: [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 23, 9, 32), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 23, 9, 33)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in ans['result']:
    print i['_id']
```

Comment: This will only return the first result item's `_id` - the OP is interested in getting all of the `_id` values.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your trace it seems that c is a dictionary containing various other dictionary.

```
print ans["result"][0]["_id"]
```

Should return the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

`func()` is actually returning a **nested dictionary**. Look closely at what your print is telling you.
So `ans = func()` is a nested dictionary:

```
{u'ok': 1.0, u'result': [{u'price': 129.7, u'_id': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 23, 9, 32)}, {u'price': 129.78, u'_id': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 23, 9, 33)},
```

Hence ans['result'] is itself another dict, or apparently a list containing a dict.